# Assigning value to another the combo box from a combox and a text input field

Tags: javascript, html, select

I am trying to assign the value to another combobox from one combobox and text input field through a function in Javascript. My function gives NaN value in console. Please guide me where I am going wrong.
Here is the code:

```js
        function myCalculatedFunction(){
        var num1;
        var num2;
        var total;
        num1=document.calcu.cc_package.value;
        num2=document.calcu.cc_unitP.value;
        total=num1*num2;
        document.getElementById("output").text=total;
        }
```

```html
        <form class="center" name="calcu">
          <fieldset>
            
         
            <label for="sel1" class="text"> Rental Mining Server- CC Package:</label>
              <select class="form-control styleSelect" id="sel1" name="cc_package" >
                <option>1,000.0000000</option>
                <option>2</option>
                <option>3</option>
                <option>4</option>
              </select>
              <br>
           <br>
           <div class="form-group">
          <label for="CC_UnitPrice" class="text"> Buy- CC Unit Price in USD</label>
          <input type="text" class="form-control" id="CC_UnitPrice" name="cc_unitP" onchange="myCalculatedFunction()">
        
       <label for="CC_PackagePrice" class="text">   CC Package Price in :</label>
          <select class="form-control styleSelect" id="CC_PackagePrice">
            <option id="output"> 0</option>
            <option>2</option>
            <option>3</option>
            <option>4</option>
          </select>
        </div>
          </fieldset>
        </form>
```

Comment: 1,000 isn't a valid number.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No need to apply `,` inside the values of select `1000.0000`.

just apply with plain number.
 Apply with [parseInt()](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_obj_math.asp) It's parse your string.

And finaly apply the calcualtion any one of the 
[Math.function](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_obj_math.asp)

```js
function myCalculatedFunction(){
        var num1;
        var num2;
        var total;
        num1=document.calcu.cc_package.value;
        num2=document.calcu.cc_unitP.value;
      //total=num1*num2 its also working
        total=Math.abs(parseInt(num1)*parseInt(num2));
        document.getElementById("output").text=total;
        }
```

```html
<form class="center" name="calcu">
          <fieldset>
            
         
            <label for="sel1" class="text"> Rental Mining Server- CC Package:</label>
              <select class="form-control styleSelect" id="sel1" name="cc_package" >
                <option>1000.0000000</option>
                <option>2</option>
                <option>3</option>
                <option>4</option>
              </select>
           <br>
           <br>
           <div class="form-group">
          <label for="CC_UnitPrice" class="text"> Buy- CC Unit Price in USD</label>
          <input type="text" class="form-control" id="CC_UnitPrice" name="cc_unitP" onchange="myCalculatedFunction()">
        
       <label for="CC_PackagePrice" class="text">  CC Package Price in :</label>
          <select class="form-control styleSelect" id="CC_PackagePrice">
            <option id="output"> 0</option>
            <option>2</option>
            <option>3</option>
            <option>4</option>
          </select>
        </div>
          </fieldset>
        </form>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think there is a mistake with the js code.

Try with this code:

`function myCalculatedFunction(){
        var num1;
        var num2;
        var total;
        num1=parseInt(document.calcu[1].value);
        num2=parseInt(document.calcu[2].value);
        total=num1*num2;
        document.getElementById("output").text=total;
        }`